# Accept Incoming Call from iPhone on Mac through AirPods (while Mac connected to iPhone Hotspot)?

Tags: ios, mac, bluetooth, airpods

While I'm on the train using my AirPods with my Mac, how do I accept a call from my iPhone over the AirPods while using my iPhone as a Wi-Fi hotspot?

Comment: If you have handoff set up, you can answer your phone from your Mac and then your AirPods will work, but that's a great question.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't apply for hotspot or non WiFi moments such as when im traveling on the train,

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently possible as AirPods connect to one device at a time and your Mac isn't able to accept calls unless it is on the same Wi-Fi network as your phone (Hotspot doesn't count).

Until one of those changes you'll have to ask the caller to "give me a minute to put on my headphones" (common practice) while you open Bluetooth settings on your iPhone (fastest: swipe up control center and choose AirPods in AirPlay) and connect to your AirPods. The call will automatically route to your AirPods once connected!

--

Alternatively you could get a bluetooth device such as the [Bose QuietComfort 35](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/over_ear_headphones/quietcomfort-35-wireless.html) which allows you to connect up to two devices so you could be connected to both your iPhone and Mac and switch easily between them!